# How to convert row data to columns in MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have SQL query that returns row data like this...

```
name1   aa  12
name1   bb  32
name2   aa  21
name3   aa  11
name3   bb  23
name3   cc  22
```

and and want to format it like this...

```
        aa  bb  cc
name1   12  32  0
name2   21  0   0
name3   11  23  22
```

Column results are dynamic and I can't use joins on them.

Comment: put your query here ... and try for `pivot`

Comment: Arnes check my answer and select It as correct answer If It helped for you.

Answer (score 2):

The following `PIVOT` query works as you expected.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(name VARCHAR(40), id VARCHAR(10), total INT)
INSERT INTO @table
SELECT 'name1','aa', 12 UNION
SELECT 'name1','bb', 32 UNION
SELECT 'name2','aa', 21 UNION
SELECT 'name3','aa', 11 UNION
SELECT 'name3','bb', 23 UNION
SELECT 'name3','cc', 22

SELECT name, 
ISNULL([aa], 0) AS [aa], 
ISNULL([bb], 0) AS [bb], 
ISNULL([cc], 0) AS [cc] 
FROM @table
    PIVOT( 
           SUM(total) 
           FOR id IN ([aa], [bb], [cc])
          ) AS pivTab
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae84c/1)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `PIVOT`.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp2 (
    Col1 VARCHAR(10),
    Col2 NVARCHAR(40),
    Col3 INT
);
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (Col1, Col2, Col3) 
            VALUES  ('name1', 'aa', 12), 
                    ('name1', 'bb', 32), 
                    ('name2', 'aa', 21),
                    ('name3', 'aa', 11), 
                    ('name3', 'bb', 23),
                    ('name3', 'cc', 22);

SELECT  Col1, 
        ISNULL([aa], 0) as aa, 
        ISNULL([bb], 0) as bb, 
        ISNULL([cc], 0) as cc
FROM #Temp2 
PIVOT
(
   MIN(col3)
   FOR col2 IN ([aa], [bb], [cc])
) as pvt

DROP TABLE #Temp2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Col1    aa  bb  cc
name1   12  32  0
name2   21  0   0
name3   11  23  22
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72ec35/3)